# Are .dll files normally found in system32 but now in a user’s AppData folder always suspicious?

Tags: windows, malware

I recently had to read over some malware reports and associated logs for a confirmed malware detection and subsequent infection of a Windows asset. The logs clearly show `.dll` files in a user’s `AppData` folder. These `.dll` files are named the same as `.dll`s normally found in `system32`, e.g `cryptbase.dll`.

I know that in this specific instance this was definitely malware and the unpacking of the rogue `.dll`s was part of the malware's normal process. 
I asked about this in chat and was told that the only real credible explanation for this behaviour would be malware (as it was in this instance) or very bad programming practice, and even in that case it is a scenario that is rare.

My question is twofold; is there a scenario where `.dll` files with the same name as standard `system32` `.dll`s be found in an user's `AppData` folder for any reason other than malware or poor programming?

In addition, is it fair to treat `.dll` files that are found in `AppData` and appear to be copies of `.dll` files in `system32`, as an indicator of compromise?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since Microsoft has straightened the default permissions on the `Program Files` folder, many developers have turned to `AppData` as an alternative location for their code. The logic being that an application installed this way can be updated without requiring elevation or admin level access. (Google Chrome, for instance, does this).

This also means that, sometimes, you will find legitimate libraries that usually live in the `system32` folder somewhere under the `AppData` path. These usually are run-time components (like the MSVCRT, GDI+ or capicom) that are maintained and updated by the application itself (usually because they require a specific version to work but sometimes because they are pushed as a user component instead of a system one and needs to be deployed without elevation).

That does not mean that you should find libraries belonging to the operating system there: there is no legitimate reason for, say, schannel.dll to be found there since the only application that maintain that library is the operating system.

So, dlls under `AppData` having the same name as a dll in `system32` are **not** automatically suspicious.

Comment: Out of interest, what version of Windows did Microsoft straighten out the permissions on the Programme Files folder?

Comment: It actually was always a feature of NT-based OS at least since Windows 2000 (possibly NT4) when installed over NTFS but, in Windows XP (and previous), it was mostly ignored: users where usually running as administrator. When UAC was released with Vista, things changed since even "administrators" account could not write to %programFiles% without elevation.

Answer (score 4):

While not proper for *distribution*, another reason someone might use the `%appdata%` path for system libraries would be for run-time shimming.

*Specifically*:  If I wanted to have run-time inspection into a given API contract validation (a common example being `malloc`/`free`, but this is already managed by AppVerifier) or general usage profiling, I could write a shim layer which performs the validation, then passes on to the legitimate system library.

In general, system libraries *should* be in the appropriate system or [SXS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly) path. All those with [Windows Logo Certification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3859) will adhere to this, but many apps distribute without certification.

Comment: I fail to see why shim dlls would have to be installed in %Appdata%: there is no part of the shimming process (as I understand it) that requires non-admin users to have write access to these files.

Comment: How is this not proper for distribution? Even Microsoft distributes programs this way. This ensures the application they have permission to their own dependencies without having unnecessary permission elevations/requirements. And it also helps prevent "DLL Hell" conflicts and gives the developer full control of their dependency management. Not all DLLs are Windows system files or third party libraries either. So putting those in a system folder would cause unnecessary complications for no added benefit.

Comment: @Stephane A user profile might not be allowed to access a DLL based on it's location and/or permissions or some UAC access/scope. %Appdata% is stored in the user's directory ensuring (or assuming the likelyhood) they have full access to it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it bad programming if you actually overwrite Windows' default DLLs. Putting them in another location than `System32` is a way to:

- Use an exact DLL version without depending on the system. (Example: Direct 9's DLLs aren't included by default on Windows 10, and any game that depends on that crashes)
- Update executables without admin rights (Firefox and Chrome does that)
- Overwrite a system DLL only for your app (Why would you do that in the first place)

If a software is well made, it will put DLLs in `AppData` or its installation directory instead of in `System32`.

If a malware is well made, it will put DLLs in `System32`.